# For in loop returns a string not an object

Tags: javascript

I have javascript object that contains nested objects. I want to iterate over these using a 'for in' loop but this returns a string instead of an object?

Code:

```
var myObject = {


    myNestedObject : {

        key1 : value 1 

    }

}
```

And then if i loop:

```
for(theObject in myObject){

    alert(typeof theObject);

}
```

This returns the string 'myNestedObject' but not the object itself.

Why?

Comment: Because that's the way `for ... in` loops work in JavaScript: you get the property names from the object.

Comment: So how do iterate and retrieve the actual object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`theObject` is the property key. What you want is probably:

```
for(var key in obj){
    var theObject = obj[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how `for...in` loops work. Instead write:

```
for(prop in Myobject){    
    alert(Myobject[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over the properties of an object.

```
for(key in myObject){
  var theObject = myObject[key]
  //theObject = { key1: value 1 }

  console.log(typeof theObject);
  //"object"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just own properties, in your case nested objects - not inherited ones - You should do

```
for(theObject in myObject){
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(theObject)) {
     alert(typeof myObject[theObject]);
  }
}
```

If you alert typeof `theObject` will give you the type of the object ... string - because this is the key ... not the object ... but alering `myObject[theObject]` will result `object` which is  the type of the Object.